# Cant seem to properly import a package into js file that is script sourced in my html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a js file that is script sourced in my HTML file. I want to import a package that is on my computer and a local file that is in the same folder but i keep getting an `unexpected identifier` error in my chrome dev tools.

```
import Twitter from 'twitter'
import config from './config'
console.log('the client and server are connected')

function clearMessage(){
    $('#tweets').empty()
}

function search() {
    for(var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++){
        var $text = '<p id="text">' + tweets[i].text + '</p>'
        var $username = '<p id="username">' + tweets[i].name + '</p>'
        var $tweets = $('#tweets');
        $tweets.append($text)
        $tweets.append($username)
    }
    setTimeout(function(){  
        clearMessage();
        var searched = document.getElementById("search").value;
        console.log(searched)
        params = {
            q: searched,
            count: 30,
            result_type: 'recent',
            lang: 'en'
        }
        var tw = new Twitter(config)
        tw.get('search/tweets', params, function(err, data, response){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                for(let i = 0; i < data.statuses.length; i++){
                    let text = data.statuses[i].text
                    let name = data.statuses[i].user.screen_name
                    tweets.push({text, name})
                }
            }
        })
        for(var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++){
            var $text = '<p id="text">' + tweets[i].text + '</p>'
            var $username = '<p id="username">' + tweets[i].name + '</p>'
            var $tweets = $('#tweets');
            $tweets.append($text)
            $tweets.append($username)
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: please include a picture about your error message in the dev tools

Comment: make sure you close every line with ';'

Comment: i closed it but now the error is comming on on line 1. this is what i have - `import Twitter from 'twitter';` twitter is an npm install ed package @PatrikAlexits

Comment: please provide the error message :) You missed a lot of semicolons in your code which would cause error anyway after the package is properly imported.

Comment: added the exact error: @PatrikAlexits

Comment: sometimes js throws errors that aren't actually the cause of said error.  For example, forgetting a comma in a place that its required might spit out `uncaught syntax error: unexpected  }`

Comment: Because of this, it is really difficult to troubleshoot the problem when you missed roughly 17 semi colons in your code.  We won't be much help to you unless you update your code *exactly* as you have it typed (if you already fixed the semi colons).

Comment: If i have a javascript file that is srced in the html documnent and I want to import a package that I have installed and saved, what is the syntax for that.. I added all of the semicolons an i am still getting the error @Jane

Comment: semi colons are not required. it doesn't matter if he/she omits them (other than being sloppy) EDIT: for loops.

Answer (score 1):

Quick way to check syntax error is to use jshint. Online at [jshint.com](https://jshint.com) or downloadable as a plugin or npm package at jshint.com/install.

Also if you install a package with npm, make sure you import the source from the proper directory. It should be in the "node_modules" directory in your root.

Yyou should be able to import the module with a namespace import:

```
import * as Twitter from "twitter";
```

or with the equivalent:

```
import Twitter= require("twitter");
```

Here is the more or less cleaned JS:

```
import Twitter from 'twitter';
import config from './config';
console.log('the client and server are connected');


function clearMessage(){
    $('#tweets').empty();
}

function search() {
  var $text, $username, $tweets = $('#tweets');

    for(var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++){
        $text = '<p id="text">' + tweets[i].text + '</p>';
        $username = '<p id="username">' + tweets[i].name + '</p>';
        $tweets.append($text);
        $tweets.append($username);
    }
    setTimeout(function(){  
        clearMessage();
        var searched = document.getElementById("search").value;
        console.log(searched);
        params = {
            q: searched,
            count: 30,
            result_type: 'recent',
            lang: 'en'
        };

        var tw = new Twitter(config);
        tw.get('search/tweets', params, function(err, data, response){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                for(let i = 0; i < data.statuses.length; i++){
                    let text = data.statuses[i].text;
                    let name = data.statuses[i].user.screen_name;
                    tweets.push({text, name});
                }
            }
        });

        for(var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++){
            $text = '<p id="text">' + tweets[i].text + '</p>';
            $username = '<p id="username">' + tweets[i].name + '</p>';
            $tweets.append($text);
            $tweets.append($username);
        }
    }, 10000);
}
```